# XmlDocument, XmlResolver and www.w3.org

Tags: .net, xml-serialization

One of my users had a single error while opening a file (I'm using standard xml 1.0):

```
The remote name could not be resolved: 'www.w3.org'
```

I found a post here in [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217841/net-autogenerated-web-service-client-how-do-i-avoid-requesting-schemas-from-w3o) that deals with this and it suggest setting the XmlResolver property to null. I've tried this, and all my documents still seem to load fine. However, the last thing I want is to break the file-reading mechanism of my app, so is it actually safe to disable the resolver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on whether you make use of external references. You can always write your own `XmlResolver`, allowing it to work with the files that you *do* have (I have one that reads known files from resx for example).

But the simplest option is just to disable it... and of course your unit tests will quickly identify any problem ;-p

Comment: Thanks Marc. I don't think I'm using any external references. I'm no xml expert unfortunately, so I wouldn't trust myself to test this change properly prior to releasing a new version.

What would an external reference look like? And why would the XmlDocument connect to w3 if there are no ext refs?

Comment: Mainly xsd validation, presumably?

Comment: @MarcGravell: the possible problem is entity resolution - see the answer I added.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to avoid connecting to the W3C site is to use [`XmlPreloadedResolver`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.resolvers.xmlpreloadedresolver.aspx). The `XmlPreloadedResolver` contains a number of "well-known" DTDs and (AFAIR) schemas embedded and whenever your xml contains a reference to one of these the resolver will serve it without trying to connect anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

You will have problems disabling external references if the XML being parsed uses entities that are defined in the referenced DTD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE sample SYSTEM "./sample.dtd">
<root>&text;</root>
```

where `&text;` is defined in `sample.dtd`. If you disable external references this XML will fail to load with an error `Reference to undeclared entity 'text'`

Another case is if your XML contains an in-line DTD with entities defined externally:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE dtd_sample[
  <!ENTITY text SYSTEM ".\text.txt">
]>
<root>&text;</root>
```

In this case the XML parses correctly, but `&text;` is empty instead than being the content of the `text.txt` file.

Both cases are pretty rare - especially the second one, so you should be OK.

Validation is usually not a problem: by default `XmlReader` does not do any validation, so even if it cannot load the relavant DTD/XSD this does not make any difference.

All this holds true using .NET 4.0, I did not test with other versions of the framework.