# "(503) Server Unavailable" with call to XSL Transform in Windows Server 2008

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xslt, windows-server-2008

So I run this Windows Server 2008 security update and this code block is now throwing an error:

```
using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    xslt.Transform(navigableSet, xslArgs, ms);
    ms.Position = 0;
    ret = new XPathDocument(ms);
}
return ret;
```

The error is `EXCEPTION [System]: The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.` I assume that this is Windows Server 2008 making shared memory super-secure. This means that I'll need to obtain IO permissions---right?

Comment: um... this is a bit more complicated... it seems that my XSL transformation is making calls to external servers... investigating...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, this my solution:

```
using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(SomeXmlString));
    XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(ms);
    xslt.Transform(reader, xslArgs, writer, null); //Passing null here prevents resolving...
    ms.Position = 0;
    ret = new XPathDocument(ms);
}
```

[Rasmus Faber](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217841/net-autogenerated-web-service-client-how-do-i-avoid-requesting-schemas-from-w3) had a similar problem about a year ago. My apologies for wasting time! I could just fiddle with Windows Server 2008 Firewall stuff to open up whatever closed but my code needs to be more explicit about making such calls in the first place!