# GoDaddy won't let XmlUrlResolver run

Tags: c#, .net, xslt

I am trying to write a page to host on and the code keeps throwing an exception.  I believe that the problem is that the permissions on the server will not let the subclass of XmlUrlResolver get instantiated, but I'd love some help with this please...

This code does work on my local dev box, and if I use File.ReadAllText(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/xml/home.xml")) it does work, so I am fairly certain it's not IO permissions....

Exception:

```
     Security Exception
Description: The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file.

Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException: Request failed.

Source Error:

Line 33:         t.Load(reader, null, new XsltUrlResolver());
Line 34:         sb = new StringBuilder(File.ReadAllText(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/xslt/url-encode.xslt")));
Line 35:     }
Line 36: </script>
Line 37:
```

Code (this is a simple page I'm using to try to narrow down the problem only):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" EnableViewState="false" Inherits="System.Web.UI.Page" %>

<%@ Import Namespace="Web" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Xml" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Hosting" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Xml.Xsl" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Text" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<script runat="server">
    public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    public class XsltUrlResolver : XmlUrlResolver
    {
        public override Uri ResolveUri(Uri baseUri, string relativeUri)
        {
            if (baseUri != null)
                return base.ResolveUri(baseUri, relativeUri);
            else
                return base.ResolveUri(baseUri, HostingEnvironment.MapPath(relativeUri));
        }
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // create the readers for the xml and xsl
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(File.ReadAllText(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/xslt/home.xslt"))));
        XmlReader input = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(File.ReadAllText(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/xml/home.xml"))));

        // create the xsl transformer
        XslCompiledTransform t = new XslCompiledTransform(true);
        t.Load(reader, null, new XsltUrlResolver());
        sb = new StringBuilder(File.ReadAllText(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/xslt/url-encode.xslt")));
    }
</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <%= sb.ToString() %>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GoDaddy shared hosting accounts run under [Medium Trust](http://help.godaddy.com/article/1039).   There are (at least) three possibilities for how your code may be running afoul of Medium Trust:

- The XSLT contains operations, like embedded script, which are incompatible with Medium Trust. See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/xmlandnetfx/thread/b643e335-f1b4-4fb3-b81f-f4ace3f156fa.  I'm not aware of any way around this other than removig the script.
- setting a custom `XmlResolver` may not be supported in Medium Trust (I've seen a few forums posts about this). You may need to pre-process your XML if this is true, to avoid needing a custom resolver.
- I've read online that `XmlResolver.ResolveUri` does demand full trust, so you may not be allowed to call it in your derived class. it may be OK to build your own resolver which does not call down to the base class's `ResolveUri` method.  Be very careful if you do this-- resolving URLs yourself is a great way for malicious data to get access to private files on your web server!

There's a few related threads on SO about XmlResolver, including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217841/net-autogenerated-web-service-client-how-do-i-avoid-requesting-schemas-from-w3o), which may be useful.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It is a conundrum. I am no longer passing in an XmlResolver but have put the fully qualified web address of the imported stylesheets. This has resolved the problem with the test page, but my full code still throws security exceptions.

Comment: can you add the call stack of the exception to your question? this will help to understand where it's failing now that you fixed the first resolver issue.  Also, does your stylesheet contain any scripts?  Sounds like scripts cannot be included in a compiled stylesheet under medium trust.

Comment: You might also want to adjust your own dev server to run in Medium Trust so you can debug closer to home-- will probably speed up diagnosis vs. having to upload to GoDaddy each time you try a fix. :-)